# Problemas con el Margin Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, margin

En un proyecto he insertado un elemento `h1` al cual deseo darle un margen de 25 px, el problema es que al darle el margen el elemento que lo contiene en este caso el `section` tambien se recorre.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
section{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

nav li:hover{
  background: rgba(46, 181,187, 0.8);
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  border-color: rgb(168, 81, 138);
}

nav button:hover{
  background: rgba(46, 181,187, 0.8);
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  color: rgb(168, 81, 138);
}

#section2 .titulo{
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=se, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/estilo.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="1"></section>
    
    <nav id="menuPrincipal" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class=""><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#1">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#2">Acerca</a>
      </li>
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
      </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</nav>

    <section id="section2" class="bg-primary mt-0">
        <h1 class="mt-5">a</h1>
           
    </section>
    <section id="3"></section>
    <section id="4"></section>
    
    <footer></footer>

    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en que realmente lo que deseas utilizar es un **[padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)**, no un **[margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)**; si bien no me especializo mucho en diseño, tengo entendido que el padding *controla los espaciados de un elemento hijo*, que en este caso sería tu `H1`.
Sólo debes cambiar `margin-top` por `padding-top`; ahora bien, en tu `CSS` haces referencia a una clase titulo que no alcanzo a ver, por lo que en este caso debiera ser

```
#section2 h1{
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Nos cuentas si es lo que querías.

Saludos

Comment: Igual el problema es que al querer aplicar un marginado el elemento padre es el que se mueve

Comment: @FernyCortez agrega `!important` y prueba otra vez